# How to find optimal function to minimize the distance to a set of points

Tags: functions, regression, data-analysis

I've been working on a side project and I had to gather some data to look for a pattern. I need to find the optimal function that minimizes the Y distance for all the points in the dataset, and so far I used Geogebra to generate both a Polynomial Regression (degree 4) and a Linear Regression. However, I'm not positive whether using regression is the correct/best way to do so, as I've never worked with them.

The function I ended up using is a mix of both of them (for x <= 80, polynomial regression, else, linear regression).

This is what the graph looks like

[image]

(note: only the blue points are counted, the other ones are older/not accurate)

Is there any better way to optimize this function or any other method I could use to achieve better results?

Comment: look into cluster analysis

Comment: @NeuroEng this might be what I'm looking for. I'll look into it, thank you

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "minimize the $y$-distance". Do you want to minimize the *maximum* $y$-distance? or the *sum* of the absolute $y$-distances? or the sum of the *squares* of the $y$-distances?

Comment: The sum of the absolute distances

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this $L_1$ regression problem via linear programming.  See problem L1 in [this example](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_016/ormpex/ormpex_ex11_toc.htm).